# How to solve "Expression expected" error in Airpush Ad integration? (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, expression, airpush, object-expected

I followed the Airpush [Installation Instructions](http://docs.airpush.com/index.php?title=Standard_SDK_9.01#Installation_Instructions) but when I use this line in Android Studio,

```
main=new Main(this, AdListener);
```

I get the error, "Expression Expected". What does this mean?

Comment: added link, removed noise

Comment: @Zac 1,Did you solve the problem? if so please answer how?

Answer (score 0):

It should look this way:

```
 private AdListener adListener;
 main = new Main(this, adListener);
```